# Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

"Поскольку в данном случае изменяется одно из обязательных условий трудового договора — срок его действия, то издание приказа необходимо" - а именно нужно ли здесь второе тире и немного смущает предлог "то".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:

1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая: Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, ***то*** понял бы источник ошибки;

В вашем примере запятая закрывает придаточное предложение, которое заканчивается приложением и перед которым стоит тире. Второе тире не нужно, оно поглощается запятой.

Подробнее об этом здесь: [Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)